# Symfony 1.4 Propel: escaping values in custom SQL queries?

Tags: mysql, symfony, escaping, symfony-1.4, propel

I have several custom SQL queries with user inputs, for example a person search. I know addslashes() is not reliable, but I cannot use mysqli_real_escape_string() or a PDO Statement with Propel, can I?

Example of a peer method:

```
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addAsColumn("lastnameRelevance", "CASE WHEN ".self::LAST_NAME." LIKE '".addslashes($query)."%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END");
$criterion = $criteria->getNewCriterion(self::NAME_NORMALIZED, "%".$query."%", Criteria::LIKE);
$criteria->add($criterion);
$criteria->addDescendingOrderByColumn("lastnameRelevance");
$criteria->addAscendingOrderByColumn(self::NAME_NORMALIZED);
return self::doSelectJoinAll($criteria);
```

If I do not add addslashes() to the $query it's pretty easy to do SQL injections.
But for mysqli_real_escape_string() I would need a $link, which I haven't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Halleluja, I think I found the solution:

```
Propel::getConnection()->quote($userInput)
```

This does the magic. Quoting and escaping in one step!
So the custom query would be:

```
$criteria->addAsColumn("lastnameRelevance", "CASE WHEN ".self::LAST_NAME." LIKE ".Propel::getConnection()->quote($query."%")." THEN 1 ELSE 0 END");
```

Can someone verifiy, that this is the best way to secure the input?

Comment: I would not trust it. These frameworks usually try to make job easier but in reality they do not. The best way would be to look in source code of mysql_real_escape_string and take the source and add it to your application